# Why can't I apply my JS event to my EJS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, click, ejs

I would like to apply a click event to the image in my EJS file, here is the ejs code:

```
<div class="container" id="comments">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="well">
                <div id="scrollit">
                    <% greword.Comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
                    <strong><p id="author"><%= comment.author %></p></strong>
                    <i id="likesi" class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i><span id="likes"><%= comment.likes %></span>
                    <i id="dislikesi" class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i><span id="dislikes"><%= comment.dislikes %></span>
                    <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
                    <p>
                        <%= comment.text %>
                    </p>
                    <% }) %>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$("#comments .row .col-lg-12 .well #scrollit").on("click", "#dislikesi", function(){

console.log("OK");

});
```

I have checked that my ejs file has been linked to JS file successfully. But strangely, it doesn't work. I can not figure it out, can somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

//*********************************************** Update!!! ***********************************************//

I have realized that I misused IDs, because the forEach function will generate multiple IDs. So I changed my codes. Here is my new ejs codes of that forEach function:

```
<% greword.Comments.forEach(function(comment, index){ %>
                    <strong><p id="author"><%= comment.author %></p></strong>
                    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i><span class="likes"><%= comment.likes %></span>
                    <i class="far fa-thumbs-down <%= index %>"></i><span class="dislikes"><%= comment.dislikes%></span>
                    <%= index %>
                    <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
                    <p>
                        <%= comment.text %>
                    </p>
                    <% }) %>
```

And I use this as JS codes:

```
$("#comments #scrollit").on("click", ".2", function(){

console.log("OK");

});
```

in order to click the 3rd comment's dislikes image. But it still doesn't work.

//*********************************************** Update!!! ***********************************************//

Thanks so much to "LGSon", my codes finally work properly.

Comment: Why can't you simply do `$("body").on("click", "#dislikesi", function(){...`

Comment: Probably because you have multiple IDs with the same name, element IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update after question edit*

A class can't just be a number, like `2`, hence `.2` won't work as a selector, it needs to be e.g. `idx2`.

The below shows exactly what you need to do, to make all e.g. `dislikesi` *buttons* fire when clicked on, as with a unique class with an index, only one will, as there will be only one item with that value.

---

*Original answer*

As it appear, you code repeats an unknown group of elements, and since several of them have a fixed `id`, your selector won't work properly, as an `id` is suppose to be unique.

If the `id` can't be unique, use the attribute selector `[attribute='value']` to target them, e.g.

```
$("#scrollit").on("click", "[id='dislikesi']", function(){

  console.log("OK");

});
```

---

Another option would be to use that elements type and class name instead, e.g.

```
$("#scrollit").on("click", "i.fa-thumbs-down", function(){

  console.log("OK");

});
```

---

Also, as `id` are suppose to be unique, you can use `forEach` 2nd argument *index* to make them, e.g. something like this `id="likesi<%= index %>"`

```
              <% greword.Comments.forEach(function(comment,index){ %>
                <strong><p id="author"><%= comment.author %></p></strong>
                <i id="likesi<%= index %>" class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i><span id="likes"><%= comment.likes %></span>
                <i id="dislikesi<%= index %>" class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i><span id="dislikes"><%= comment.dislikes %></span>
                <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
                <p>
                    <%= comment.text %>
                </p>
              <% }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answers. Your third suggestion enlightened me and I realized that I probably misused IDs. My main purpose is to build a comment function with likes and dislikes just like FaceBook's comment. I use forEach function to support users to submit their comments, so it will give multiple IDs. So I changed my code, here is my new codes of forEach function:

Comment: `<% greword.Comments.forEach(function(comment, index){ %>
      <strong><p id="author"><%= comment.author %></p></strong>
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i><span class="likes"><%= comment.likes %></span>
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-down <%= index %>"></i><span class="dislikes"><%= comment.dislikes%></span>
      <%= index %>
      <span class="pull-right">10 days ago</span>
      <p>
       <%= comment.text %>
      </p>
      <% }) %>`

Comment: And I use `$("#comments #scrollit").on("click", ".2", function(){

    console.log("OK");

});` But it still doesn't work, I am so confused.

Comment: @chris First off, a class can't just be a number, like `2`, hence `.2` won't work as a selector, it needs to be e.g. `idx2`. Second, if you add a unique class like that to the click handler, it will only fire for that element with that unique class, and I assume you don't want that as it will be different for every _button_. In my answer I show exactly what you need to do, using a class that is the same on all those _buttons_.